# Can ftell use for non-ASCII characters?

Tags: c++

This line

```
Assert(pos == ftell(file));
```

is used in my code, when file contains non-ASCII characters, this line failed.

What should I do?

To make it clear, here is the whole function updated:

```
int getTerminatedString(char * dest, int length) 
{
    char * rv  = fgets(dest,length,file);
    int len = -1;
    if(rv)
    {
        len = strlen(rv);
        pos += len;
        assert(pos == ftell(file));

    }
    return len;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should use "libicu".

Comment: What do you mean by non-ASCII characters? C does not know ASCII.

Comment: C++ or C?  They're not the same, and you'll get different answers.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "failed"?

Comment: That assert fails if "pos " is not equal to "ftell(file)" - which will happen if the file is opened as a text-file and you are pos is the number of characters you have read, for example. But that's not the only way it could fail. Seeing ONLY this line makes it completely impossible to say why/how/when it will and won't fail [we'd also need to understand what OS, etc]

Comment: I tried to use all english words file, code runs fine. but when I use a file  containing Hebrew characters, this line fails. I get: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".

Comment: There is no double colon in C. Maybe you mean C++ ?

Comment: `pos` is still a mistery

Comment: Right, so we need to understand what your code does to get to that point. Hebrew most likely is using Unicode encoding - which may be a 8-bit UTF, 16-bit UTF or "Windows Unicode" (16-bits, limited to the lower 64K unicode characters) or "Linux Unicode" (32-bit, allows ALL unicode characters known so far).

Comment: If the input contains NULs ( '\0' ) strlen will report a shorter length ( upto the first NUL) than how much was actually read by fgets. See man fgets and man strlen.

Comment: You should give a minimal working example, not just a function with weird pointers and undeclared identifiers. E.g. if the `dest` pointer is wrong the program may overwrite the `file` variable - that is a possible `SIGABRT`

Comment: Sorry, it is in C++. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Right, so depending on what strlen and fgets does when it encounters hebrew characters, it will potentially be different yes. strlen may well count several bytes as one character.

Comment: You could print the position of the file plus the accumulated length and than inspect a hexdump of the file at the particular position(s). BTW: pos is undefined.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Actually I don't think strlen works properly on multibyte characters - so it should count the same as ftell.

Comment: I agree, it probably doesn't. What it actually does is another matter - does it count the characters as individual bytes or some other way? How is the actual data encoded?

Comment: If the question is about C++, then you should be using some variant of `basic_string` which can handle null characters appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the file in binary mode e.g. `fopen("yourfile","rb")`, `ftell` will give the offset in the file regardless of content.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `dest` buffer large enough to contain all the characters AND a final terminating zero byte as well?

If the buffer pointer by the `dest` pointer is too small the program may overwrite in the memory something it should not - that is one possible way to get the SIGABRT.